# how to have grease pencil animation have one object permanent

Tags: grease-pencil

I am trying to make a 2d animation in blender and appreciate the grease pencil tools. However, I find it hard to say keep a tree in the background for multiple frames. Is there a way to make one layer remain constant when adding new frames? I have tried locking the layer, but that in turn locks everything which I don't want. If I want a guy to walk in to a city, I want the landscape locked, but the character himself not. How should I go about doing this?
Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm also trying to do that and I think what we need is multiple greasepencil objects, but how?

Answer (score 1):

Like wilks suggests, the easiest route might be to add another grease pencil object for background elements. The images below show one way to do that.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]